# Node.JS and Vue.JS Post action

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api, vue.js

I ran into a problem where I try to do a POST action with Vue.JS to my Node.JS app.
The problem is that I can't receive "data" in the Node.JS app every time I get undefined in console.log
here are my screens.
[Node.JS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsKmE.png)
[Vue.JS action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx4F4.png)

[undefined error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kns8i.png)

[Vue.JS html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXUgi.png)

Comment: You have incomplete information. Please elaborate with proper code/image and errors

Comment: if you are using expressjs there is no request.data, that's why it is undefined. You must get the data as you do in the request.body. 

Maybe you also have a problem with your setup. Please have a look in that link from express: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so the Problem was that i was missing:

app.use(express.json()) // for parsing application/json
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Ref answer from Ricardo expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body